# How can I use a full URL string (with query params) in routerLink directive?

Tags: angular

Consider this object that returns from an internal CMS

```
export declare interface ContentItem {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    subTitle: string;
    clickUrl: string;
    imageUrl: string;
    contentType: string;
    ...
}
```

The `clickUrl` will have a complete url that navigate to valid angular route. I was looking for a way to use this url in `routerLink` directive; something like this

```
<a [routerLink]="contentItem.clickUrl">click me</a>
```

My problem is when this url contains a query params. The directive will escape '?', '=' and '&' characters from the url.

I know that we can pass query params like this:

```
[queryParams]="{ articleId: contentItem.id }"
```

However, This does not work without stripping the query params part from `clickUrl` previously mentioned.

Comment: The url is still relative, right? (it does not contains host)

Comment: Yes the url is relative without a host.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `routerLink`, you can use the controller for this.

```
<a (click)="goTo(contentItem.clickUrl)">click me</a>
```

In controller:

```
this.goTo(url) {
  this.router.navigateByUrl(url);
}
```

Comment: This question is for angular not angularjs. Also using a function to handle click event does not generate `href` on `<a></a>`; instead, it will create click event handler. This is not the best for SEO

Comment: the above solution is also for angular, not angularjs. And its a SPA, so seo will not work anyways.

Comment: Its not recommended to do this. The anchor needs the href. It will remove Accessibility features?

Answer (score 0):

As I am seeing your problem is basically that you need to persist previous query params but also add new. Angular comes with an option 'queryParamsHandling' to either preserve or merge. By default the query parameters are lost on any subsequent navigation action:

```
this.router.navigate(['/url'], { queryParamsHandling: 'preserve' });
```

It's also possible to use 'merge' option

e.g.

```
this.router.navigate(['/url?order=popular'], { queryParams: { filter: 'new'}, queryParamsHandling: 'merge' });
// result http://localhost/url?order=popular&filter=new
```